# System.ArgumentNullException on feature enabling

Tags: 2010, powershell

I created a vs solution with

- site columns
- content type
- list template
- list instance.

It compiles, it installs correctly, except when I click on activate I got the exception on the ULS logs:

> System.ArgumentNullException: Key cannot be null. Parameter name: key on feature activation

Site Columns

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Field ID="{204D9564-56ED-4D71-BB36-BCBA4B316337}" Name="ExternalSiteUrl" 
         DisplayName="ExternalSiteUrl" Type="Text" Group="Mirage Teams Columns" 
         Required="TRUE"></Field>
  <Field ID="{AFBCD50B-6C45-4B64-9589-194B5133978C}" Name="ExternalSiteDescription" 
         DisplayName="ExternalSiteDescription" Type="Text" Group="Mirage Teams Columns" 
         MaxLength="255"  Required="TRUE"></Field>
</Elements>
```

Content type:

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <!-- Parent ContentType: Item (0x01) -->
  <ContentType ID="0x01003098bdc2a2534bae9c08f5701ea4f89f"
               Name="CTExternalSites"
               Group="Mirage Teams Content Types"
               Description="Content Type for External Sites"
               Inherits="TRUE"
               Version="0">
    <FieldRefs>
      <FieldRef ID="{204D9564-56ED-4D71-BB36-BCBA4B316337}" Name="ExternalSiteUrl"></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef ID="{AFBCD50B-6C45-4B64-9589-194B5133978C}" Name="ExternalSiteDescription"></FieldRef>
    </FieldRefs>
  </ContentType>
</Elements>
```

List Template

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <!-- Do not change the value of the Name attribute below. If it does not match the folder name of the List Definition project item, an error will occur when the project is run. -->
    <ListTemplate
        Name="ListExternalSites"
        Type="10000"
        BaseType="0"
        OnQuickLaunch="TRUE"
        SecurityBits="11"
        Sequence="410"
        DisplayName="External Sites"
        Description="External Sites List Template"
        Image="/_layouts/images/itgen.png"/>
</Elements>
```

List Instance

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <ListInstance Title="SlnMirageTeamsCustomization - ListInstanceExternalSites"
                OnQuickLaunch="TRUE"
                TemplateType="10000"
                Url="Lists/ExternalSites"
                Description="External Sites">
  </ListInstance>
</Elements>
```

Schema.xml

```
<List xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint" Title="External Sites" FolderCreation="FALSE" Direction="$Resources:Direction;" Url="Lists/SlnMirageTeamsCustomization-ListExternalSites" BaseType="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <MetaData>
    <ContentTypes>
      <ContentType ID="0x01003098bdc2a2534bae9c08f5701ea4f89f" Name="CTExternalSites" Group="Mirage Teams Content Types" Description="Content Type for External Sites" Inherits="TRUE" Version="0">
        <FieldRefs>
          <FieldRef ID="{204D9564-56ED-4D71-BB36-BCBA4B316337}" Name="ExternalSiteUrl"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef ID="{AFBCD50B-6C45-4B64-9589-194B5133978C}" Name="ExternalSiteDescription"></FieldRef>
        </FieldRefs>
      </ContentType>
    </ContentTypes>
    <Fields>
      <Field ID="{204d9564-56ed-4d71-bb36-bcba4b316337}" Name="ExternalSiteUrl" DisplayName="ExternalSiteUrl" Type="Text" Group="Mirage Teams Columns" Required="TRUE">
      </Field>
      <Field ID="{afbcd50b-6c45-4b64-9589-194b5133978c}" Name="ExternalSiteDescription" DisplayName="ExternalSiteDescription" Type="Text" Group="Mirage Teams Columns" MaxLength="255" Required="TRUE">
      </Field>
    </Fields>
    <Views>
      <View BaseViewID="0" Type="HTML" MobileView="TRUE" TabularView="FALSE">
        <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
        <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
        <ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="LinkTitleNoMenu">
          </FieldRef>
        </ViewFields>
        <Query>
          <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name="Modified" Ascending="FALSE">
            </FieldRef>
          </OrderBy>
        </Query>
        <ParameterBindings>
          <ParameterBinding Name="AddNewAnnouncement" Location="Resource(wss,addnewitem)" />
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_ONET_HOME)" />
        </ParameterBindings>
      </View>
      <View BaseViewID="1" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="$Resources:core,objectiv_schema_mwsidcamlidC24;" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileView="TRUE" MobileDefaultView="TRUE" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/generic.png" Url="AllItems.aspx">
        <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
        <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
        <ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="LinkTitleNoMenu"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="ExternalSiteUrl"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="ExternalSiteDescription"></FieldRef>
          <!--<FieldRef Name="Attachments">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle">
          </FieldRef>-->
        </ViewFields>
        <Query>
          <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name="ID">
            </FieldRef>
          </OrderBy>
        </Query>
        <ParameterBindings>
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)" />
        </ParameterBindings>
      </View>
    </Views>
    <Forms>
      <Form Type="DisplayForm" Url="DispForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      <Form Type="EditForm" Url="EditForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      <Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
    </Forms>
  </MetaData>
</List>
```

I am using the following to install

```
Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath "D:\27022012\SlnMirageTeamsCustomization\SlnMirageTeamsCustomization\bin\Debug\SlnMirageTeamsCustomization.wsp"
Install-SPSolution –Identity SlnMirageTeamsCustomization.wsp -GACDeployment -Force 

# Install-SPFeature use it only after installing or upgrading the solution
Install-SPFeature "SlnMirageTeamsCustomization_FeatureExternalSites" -force
Enable-SPFeature "SlnMirageTeamsCustomization_FeatureExternalSites" -Url http://xxx/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try
Another tag closing way:

```
<FieldRef ID="{835674F1-BEFC-4187-A707-36A336231DD4}" Name="Start" />
```

Comment: Wow. This little thing fixed it. I cant believe it.